# Is flat file blog SEO friendly?

Tags: database, file, blogs, flat

I want to create an online blog using flat file database, but I'm not sure if the posts are going to be indexed by Google. I wanted to use MySQL, but search engines don't see the posts. So I thought maybe flat file db will do the trick, but I'm not sure, can't find any answers online.
I'm also wondering if Google will index my .txt files (the db itself)?

Thank you.

Comment: Ahh.. Huh? Google will not index your database at all. It will index that which you publish through a webserver, regardless of storage on your hard drive.

Comment: If you can browse your website, Google can. Your db is never exposed so it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't matter to Google what kind of database you use, in fact, it can't tell the difference. The only thing Google gets to see is your public-facing webpages (obviously). If

Google indexes your page it follows every link, so if you put links to your .txt files it will index them. However, this is unneccessary and a bad idea at that (you wouldn't want your users to see them).

If you want to be sure Google indexes your page you can submit it to Google yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Google will index the web pages your site generates.  It doens't know or care whether those pages are backed by a database, a txt file, or just somebody typing really really fast